# Special kind of php regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following regular expression is valid for my string,

```
$t = "('Blah.blahh', 'blahh')";
$pattern = "/\((?:[^{}]+|(?R))*\)/";
```

But I need modify this regular expression to match  "_t('Blah.blahh', 'blahh')" .

Does any one has idea how to write a expression for "_t('Blah.blahh', 'blahh')"?

Comment: I've got to ask... why do you want to match this? It looks like you're matching a bit of PHP code (a language translation function cal?), but I can't work out why. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? This has a strong smell of something that is going down a complex path to achieve something for which there may be a much simpler solution.

Comment: It is to pull messages to translate from php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$pattern = "_t\((?:[^{}]+|(?R))*\)";
```

Comment: $reg = '/,([0-9])\:/s'
This is the regex for ,anyNumber: